Manhwa - ML transmigrates to an alternate universe where the FL actually loves him
The male lead (ML) is a typical black haired ML (Idk if this is accurate) and he keeps trying really hard to make the female lead (FL) fall in love with him (he was a king) and he kind of kills FL's friends and family in the process, making her insane and then she took her own life.
Now, the ML literally spent the rest of his life with FL's body. And, he got transmigrated in an alternate universe where this time, the FL was obsessed with him. The FL got married to him at a young age, and then she helped him become emperor. Once he did, she tried her best to become empress and pregnant with his child (I think) and then the ML transmigrated after that event.
And I also kind of think that this is a smut manhwa, but I don't know too.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Hmmm, most I remember is that the FL is a blonde...
